# Comparing two identical strings returns false (Python 3)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, compare, string-comparison

I have a code where I have a list of strings that I compare to strings from a text file input (word by word). This code is for a project I have that involves identifying some keywords.

In my text file, I have a single word per line. So it would look like this:

sucks

cool

interesting

---

This is the code:

```
list = ["that sucks", "Better luck next time!"]

for x in list:
    f = open ("keywords.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")

    for l in range (1, 4):
        s = f.readline()

        for y in x.split():
            if str(y) == str(s):
                print (y)
    f.close()
```

I have tried printing the results of y == s and kept on getting false for all cases and I have no idea why...

Comment: The lines you read from the file all end in a newline character: `\n`, but the words you split from that list don't have newlines. BTW, you shouldn't use `list` as a variable name because that shadows the built-in `list` type.

Comment: the string returned by `readline` will have a **newline** character appended. Try with `s.rstrip('\n')`.

Comment: try with `s.strip()`

Comment: @PRMoureu that would remove *all* whitespace from both beginning and end.

Comment: yes! Used s.replace("\n", ""). Worked like a charm! Thank you all!! :)

Comment: @PM2Ring will keep that in mind, thanks!